# Modelling ternary relations in a semantic wiki

Tags: semantic-mediawiki

Standard example to model a binary relation is "Dad likes Mom". In a Wiki I would have two pages for Mom and Dad and a (directed) property "likes".

I need to model "ternary relations". For example:

- Peter goes to New York using a bus.
- John goes to Mexico using a car.

Where people, locations be vehicles are entities and usage is the ternary property/relation.

**How can I express that in a semantic mediawiki??**

Comment: I'm not seeing why you've tagged this `relational-algebra`

Comment: Relational Algebra is independent of the arity of relations I think. And people thinking about relations algebraically might have an idea how to model this.

Comment: @philipxy: a simple predicate is "A likes B". That's very easy to implement. ternary statements are not that easy, but perhaps it can be substituted by simple statements.

Comment: This is unclear & not researched. "a semantic wiki" is nothing specific (though you tag with semantic-mediawiki) & "generally with simple predicates" & "RA is independent of the arity of relations" are unclear. Ask a clear specific non-duplicate question where you are stuck in some specific task or presentation--an answer depends on context.  Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers.

Comment: Googling '(ternary OR n-ary) (predicates OR relations) "semantic" (web OR mediawiki) with & without site:stackoverflow.com' ... [Defining N-ary Relations on the Semantic Web](http://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations) [How can I express additional information (time, probability) about a relation in RDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32923213/3404097) [How do I define relation properties in OWL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22120071/3404097) [Representing complicated sentences using RDF syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16476051/3404097) See [ask], [help] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: No matches for semantic mediawiki though...

Comment: Yes, there are, including links to the mediawiki wiki. Which you should have checked anyway as the manual for a system you are using.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This cant be done with standard means. The ternary relation needs to be represented as an object in its own right using 
https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Type_Record

This is implemented using:
https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Semantic_Internal_Objects